# Unable to deploy smartcontract using web3j and Rinkbey infura

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, rinkeby, web3j, java

I'm trying to deploy a smartcontract on Rinkbey. I've followed the official documentation and some tutorials. I implemented the following code in my android studio but `contract.deploy` returns nothing.

```
private fun connectWithRinkBey() {
//        web3j = Web3j.build(InfuraHttpService(rinkBeyUrl))
        val web3j = Web3j.build(HttpService("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/786cbf2ff21241c583732b7a1741880a"))
        try {
            val clientVersion = web3j.web3ClientVersion()
                .sendAsync().get()
            if (!clientVersion.hasError()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                Log.d(TAG, "deployContract2: Starting")
                Log.d(TAG, "deployContract2: ${deployContract2()}")
                Log.d(TAG, "connectWithRinkBey: Ending")

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, clientVersion.error.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

private fun deployContract2(): String {
        val transactionManager = RawTransactionManager(web3j, getCredentialsFromPrivateKey())
        val contractGasProvider = StaticGasProvider(gasPrice, gasLimit)
        return Trust_sol_Trust.deploy(web3j, transactionManager, contractGasProvider)
            .send()
            .contractAddress
    }
```

Comment: Rinkeby Deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Rinkeby is almost deprecated. Check this [warning](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/).
Migrate your contracts and deploy new ones on Goerli or Sepolia. The only two testnets developers will maintain after the merge.

Comment: Rinkeyby is working fine in Javascript.